# CMake: CMakeLists for C11

Tags: cmake, ide, clion, c11

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Example)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm learning C11 and I'm using CLion IDE.
In this IDE only possible option is use of CMake for projects, and I read a few manuals of CMake (in stack overflow, too), and I don't find ready solution to write correct CMakeLists for C11 projects.

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
```

This line set C11 standard.

```
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC TRUE)
```

This line set gcc as compiler.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
```

This line set compilation flags to default of IDE.

Is my CMakeLists.txt correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
set(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC TRUE)
```

`CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC` should only be read to test what compiler correspond to your current generator, something like:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    # do something special for GNU C compiler
endif()
```

Just remove it. You may want to read [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207251865-How-can-I-change-compilers-in-CLion-), if you need to specify your compiler (but you should not need to).

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
```

This line does absolutely nothing: you set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` with its own content. Just remove it.

> Is my CMakeLists.txt correct?

When building, does CLion tell you it isn't?

Comment: Thank you. I removed that lines and it's working faster at loading symbols step.